# Show that a set is not open

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose  $U_1$ and $U_2$ are both nonempty subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that $U_1 \cap U_2 =\emptyset $ and $U_1\cup U_2 = \mathbb R.$

Consider points $p \in U_1\ \text{and}\ q \in U_2.$ Without loss of generality, we may assume that $p < q.$

Now, let $A$ be the set of all points $x \in U_1$ with $x< q.$ We know that $A$ is nonempty (since $p \in A$) and that it has an upper bound (since $q$ is an upper bound for $A$). Thus $A$ must have a least upper bound, call it $m.$

Suppose that $m \in U_1$. Show that $U_1$ not open.

[Is it possible to prove with the definition of an Open Set in Metric Space?

Definition: Let X be a metric space, and let U be a subset of X. We say that U is open if, for every point p ∈ U, there is some real number ε > 0 such that Bε(p) ⊂ U.

Note: Bε(p) is the set of all points x in X such that d(x, p) < ε.]

Comment: Can you clarify your question: are you trying to show that $U_1$ is open or is not open?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The question is to show U1 is not open.

Comment: Find a sequence in $(m,m+\epsilon)$ in $U_2$ that converges to $m\in U_1$.

Comment: For each $n\in\mathbb N$ there must be an element of $U_2$ in $(m,m+1/n)$.

Comment: Because if not then $q>m+1/n$ for some $n$ and $[m,m+1/n]$ must be in $U_1$ contradicting the definition of $m$.

Comment: How to show such sequence exist?

Answer (score 1):

If possible let us assume that $U_1$ is open and since $m\in U_1$ so there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(m-\epsilon,m+\epsilon) \subset U_1$. Now there are two possibilities, either $q \in (m-\epsilon,m+\epsilon)$ or $q\notin (m-\epsilon,m+\epsilon)$.

But you can clearly see that the only possibility is actually $q \notin (m-\epsilon,m+\epsilon)$ because $U_1\cap U_2 =\emptyset$. But if $q \notin (m-\epsilon,m+\epsilon)$ then this  is a contradiction to fact that $m$ was supremum.